Cannot run .NET Core application on Linux in Azure App Services with linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE:8.0'
When I define my .NET Core application to run on Linux in Azure App Services with linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE:8.0' and reserved: true, I keep getting HTTP 404 responses from Nginx.
The application works fine on Windows in Azure App Services.
Looking at the logs, it seems like App Services is downloading a PHP image, which outputs a version of PHP 8.0.x.
Has anyone experienced something similar and knows how to fix it?

Code:
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  sku: environmentConfigurationMap[environment].appServicePlan.sku
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}

resource appServiceApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServiceAppName
  location: location
  identity: { type: 'SystemAssigned' }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE:8.0'
      // netFrameworkVersion: 'v8.0'
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: applicationInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: applicationInsights.properties.ConnectionString
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Error:



Try DOTNETCORE|8.0 instead of DOTNETCORE:8.0?

@RuiJarimba Thank you for your suggestion. But shouldn't I use a value output by az webapp list-runtimes --os-type linux? In that case, I can specify DOTNETCORE:[6-8].0

Give it a try. I've seen a few posts where people are using the DOTNETCORE|x.x syntax.

@RuiJarimba It worked! I'm even allowed to set arbitrary values for the runtime stack: az webapp config set --name todo-app-rbqkyp2g5zxmq --resource-group todoapptest --linux-fx-version 'DOTNETFOO:4.0'

@RuiJarimba Where are these values documented, if Azure isn't documenting them themselves? IMHO, this is very messy. No input validation, Azure CLI not outputting real values, ...

TBH I couldn't find the official Microsoft documentation regarding this setting.

But given this is an enterprise Azure service, how would others go about looking up proper runtime values? They are revealed in random blog posts, or?

Maybe proper values can be "reverse engineered" from the Azure Portal web source?

Actually the az webapp config set command documentation shows the right syntax for each runtime stack, even though it won't display all the valid versions for each one: --linux-fx-version - The runtime stack used for your linux-based webapp, e.g., "RUBY|2.5.5", "NODE|12LTS", "PHP|7.2", "DOTNETCORE|2.1"

Thank you. Then az webapp list-runtimes need to be fixed :)

The right syntax for setting a .NET version in linuxFxVersion is DOTNETCORE|x.x, even for .NET 6 or .NET 8.
So instead of:
DOTNETCORE:8.0

Use:
DOTNETCORE|8.0

Available built-in stacks for Web Apps and Function Apps
You can run the az webapp list-runtimes to list the available built-in stacks which can be used for web apps, but as mentioned in the comments of the question this list doesn't seem to be correct (: is not the right  separator):
C:\Users\ruija> az webapp list-runtimes --os-type linux --output table

Result
--------------------------
DOTNETCORE:9.0
DOTNETCORE:8.0
DOTNETCORE:7.0
DOTNETCORE:6.0
NODE:20-lts
NODE:18-lts
NODE:16-lts
PYTHON:3.12
PYTHON:3.11
PYTHON:3.10
PYTHON:3.9
PYTHON:3.8
PHP:8.3
PHP:8.2
PHP:8.1
PHP:8.0
JAVA:21-java21
JAVA:17-java17
JAVA:11-java11
JAVA:8-jre8
JBOSSEAP:8-java17
JBOSSEAP:8-java11
JBOSSEAP:8.0.2-java17_byol
JBOSSEAP:8.0.2-java11_byol
JBOSSEAP:7-java17
JBOSSEAP:7-java11
JBOSSEAP:7-java8
TOMCAT:10.1-java21
TOMCAT:10.1-java17
TOMCAT:10.1-java11
TOMCAT:10.0-java17
TOMCAT:10.0-java11
TOMCAT:10.0-jre8
TOMCAT:9.0-java21
TOMCAT:9.0-java17
TOMCAT:9.0-java11
TOMCAT:9.0-jre8
TOMCAT:8.5-java11
TOMCAT:8.5-jre8

Running the equivalent command for Function Apps (az functionapp list-runtimes) returns a different list:
PS C:\Users\myself> az functionapp list-runtimes --os linux --query "[].linux_fx_version" --output table

Result
-------------------
DOTNET-ISOLATED|9.0
DOTNET-ISOLATED|8.0
DOTNET-ISOLATED|7.0
DOTNET-ISOLATED|6.0
DOTNET|8.0
DOTNET|6.0
Node|22
Node|20
Node|18
Python|3.11
Python|3.10
Python|3.9
Python|3.8
Python|3.7
Java|21
Java|17
Java|11
Java|8
PowerShell|7.4
PowerShell|7.2


for anyone who comes here struggling to get this working with the dotnet-isolated model, you're looking for DOTNET-ISOLATED|8.0

Thanks for sharing @Idam. I've added more details to my answer.
